# Shell Script logic NR==FNR getting Failed for Case 2

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I have two files name as 1) File-New 2) File-Old. they contains data as shown below,

***case 1***

**File-New**

```
7! J9AA-104445-A-BOM-50! REINF RR KIT FLR S/M LH! 35!
8! J9BB-103365-A-BOM-50! MBR REINF  FLR SD LH! 22!
7! JWZZ-102225-A-MOM-50! RZFIF RR KRT FLR W/Z LH! 15!
```

**File-Old**

```
7! J9AA-104445-A-BOM-50! REINF RR KIT FLR S/M LH! 34!
8! J9BB-103365-A-BOM-50! MBR REINF  FLR SD LH! 21!
7! JWZZ-102225-A-MOM-50! RZFIF RR KRT FLR W/Z LH! 14!
```

When we run `awk -F"!" 'NR==FNR{++a[$2,$4];next} !(a[$2,$4])'` logic for both files Expected output is,

```
$ /usr/xpg4/bin/awk -F"!" 'NR==FNR{++a[$2,$4];next} 
                           !(a[$2,$4])' "File-New" "File-Old"

   7! J9AA-104445-A-BOM-50! REINF RR KIT FLR S/M LH! 34!
   8! J9BB-103365-A-BOM-50! MBR REINF  FLR SD LH! 21!
   7! JWZZ-102225-A-MOM-50! RZFIF RR KRT FLR W/Z LH! 14!
```

From output we can see the logic of command `-F"!" 'NR==FNR{++a[$2,$4];next} !(a[$2,$4])'` is written to print the difference in "File-Old". But above logic fails if the data of both files changed as shown below,

***Case 2***

**File-New**

```
7! J9AA-104445-A-BOM-50! REINF RR KIT FLR S/M LH! 35!
8! J9BB-103365-A-BOM-50! MBR REINF  FLR SD LH! 22!
7! JWZZ-102225-A-MOM-50! RZFIF RR KRT FLR W/Z LH! 15!
7! J9AA-104445-A-BOM-50! REINF RR KIT FLR S/M LH! 34!
8! J9BB-103365-A-BOM-50! MBR REINF  FLR SD LH! 21!
```

File-Old

```
7! J9AA-104445-A-BOM-50! REINF RR KIT FLR S/M LH! 34!
8! J9BB-103365-A-BOM-50! MBR REINF  FLR SD LH! 21!
7! JWZZ-102225-A-MOM-50! RZFIF RR KRT FLR W/Z LH! 14!
7! J9AA-104445-A-BOM-50! REINF RR KIT FLR S/M LH! 34!
8! J9BB-103365-A-BOM-50! MBR REINF  FLR SD LH! 21!
```

Run the same logic for **case 2**

```
$ /usr/xpg4/bin/awk -F"!" 'NR==FNR{++a[$2,$4];next} 
                           !(a[$2,$4])' "File-New" "File-Old"

   7! JWZZ-102225-A-MOM-50! RZFIF RR KRT FLR W/Z LH! 14!
```

---

**Expected Out is**

```
  7! J9AA-104445-A-BOM-50! REINF RR KIT FLR S/M LH! 34!
  8! J9BB-103365-A-BOM-50! MBR REINF  FLR SD LH! 21!
  7! JWZZ-102225-A-MOM-50! RZFIF RR KRT FLR W/Z LH! 14!
```

Is someone able to suggest what I need to change in logic **-F"!" 'NR==FNR{++a[$2,$4];next} !(a[$2,$4])'** to get the Expected output for **case 2** without changing the file order "File-New" "File-Old".

Note : we have to keep the Order of file passing to command is Fix i.e "File-New" "File-Old"

Comment: And please explain what you wish to achieve. Yes, we can see the logic of your command, but it outputs exactly what it should, so your expectations are likely wrong.

Comment: You must put clear what you want to get. Your code prints the lines of the **old** file which are different from the **new** file. But your expected output includes both common lines and **one different line**!

Comment: My expectation is after comparing two files only print the lines in which $2 is same & $4 is different. also not to print the newly added lines in File-New. 
One Expert "Valentin B" Suggested below logic 
/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -F'!' 'NR==FNR{++a[$2,$4,FNR];next} !(a[$2,$4,FNR])' "File-New" "File-Old"

this works correctly but if "File-New" contains new entry which not present in File-Old then this Logic gets failed. can anyone able to improve the above code to get above mentioned expected result.

Answer (score 1):

The `awk` snippet you are using constructs a dictionary with keys equal to values from second and fourth field (with "!" separated fields). It fails to do what you expect because for example for this line (2nd line in "File-new"):

```
8! J9BB-103365-A-BOM-50! MBR REINF  FLR SD LH! 22!
```

Which changes to this line

```
8! J9BB-103365-A-BOM-50! MBR REINF  FLR SD LH! 21!
```

There is also another line in "File-old" with identical 2nd and 4th fields. So the value at key `[J9BB-103365-A-BOM-50,21]` of array `a` is not zero, thus the line is not printed. If you wish to monitor changes to each line on these 2 fields, you must also store the line number in your array, yielding this:

```
awk -F'!' 'NR==FNR{++a[$2,$4,FNR];next} 
                       !(a[$2,$4,FNR])' "File-New" "File-Old"
```

Maybe you will wish to complete this by also printing the line number:

```
awk -F'!' 'NR==FNR{++a[$2,$4,FNR];next} 
          !(a[$2,$4,FNR]){printf "Line %d changed: %s\n", FNR, $0}' "File-New" "File-Old"
```

Output:

```
Line 1 changed: 7! J9AA-104445-A-BOM-50! REINF RR KIT FLR S/M LH! 34!
Line 2 changed: 8! J9BB-103365-A-BOM-50! MBR REINF  FLR SD LH! 21!
Line 3 changed: 7! JWZZ-102225-A-MOM-50! RZFIF RR KRT FLR W/Z LH! 14!
```

Comment: My expectation is after comparing two files only print the lines in which $2 is same & $4 is different. also not to print the newly added lines in File-New.
your suggested code work differently if File-New contains new entry which not present in File-Old.

Comment: File New 
    7! J9AA-50! LH! 35!

    8! J9BB-50! LH! 22!

    7! test3! test3! 8 

    7! JWZZ-50! LH! 15!

    7! J9AA-50! LH! 34!

    8! J9BB-50! LH! 21! 

File-Old
    7! J9AA-50! LH! 34!

    8! J9BB-50! LH! 21!

    7! JWZZ-50! LH! 14!

    7! J9AA-50! LH! 34!

    8! J9BB-50! LH! 21!

for Above case your suggested code fails, 

    /usr/xpg4/bin/awk -F'!' 'NR==FNR{++a[$2,$4,FNR];next} !(a[$2,$4,FNR])' "File-New" "File-Old"

Expected Result:

     7! J9AA-50! LH! 34!

     8! J9BB-50! LH! 21!

     7! JWZZ-50! LH! 14!

Could you please suggest change